# Conversion of HTML page to PDF in angular7

Tags: angular, pdf-generation

My intention is to convert a HTML page to PDF while clicking a button

I tried it by doing it like: 
1.html2Canvas + jspdf

```
 html2canvas(data).then(canvas => { 
const contentDataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png');
    }
```

And the output I'm getting is

```
contentDataUrl  = data:,
```

and alternatively I wrote  like this:

```
public captureScreen() { 
 var data = document.getElementById("print"); 
   html2canvas(data).then(canvas => { 
    var imgWidth = 208; 
    var pageHeight = 295; 
    var imgHeight = canvas.height * imgWidth / canvas.width; 
    var heightLeft = imgHeight; 
    const contentDataURL = canvas.toDataURL('image/png') 
    let pdf = new jspdf('p', 'mm', 'a4'); // A4 size page of PDF 
    var position = 0; 
    pdf.addImage(contentDataURL, 'PNG', 0, position, imgWidth, imgHeight) 
    pdf.save('MYPdf.pdf'); // Generated PDF 
  }); 
 }
```

I'm getting an error like:

```
Uncaught (in promise): Error: Supplied Data is not a valid base64-String jsPDF.convertStringToImageData
Error: Supplied Data is not a valid base64-String jsPDF.convertStringToImageData
at Object.x.convertStringToImageData
```

I need a valid approach to convert angular HTML page to PDF and also suggest me if any other better approaches

Note: I'm using Angular material and nested components in that html page.

Comment: There might be a dozen npm packages that do this already. Have you looked into any of them? Or, is this a learn exercise?

Comment: Could you give an example of the data that you are using? It is hard to understand what is causing the problem without it.

Comment: @R.Richards I tried only "export as" npm package it didn't work other than that I couldn't find any npm packages.I'll appreciate if u can suggest me any other approaches that can support angular material in converting angular page to PDF